# The best overloaded method match for 'double.Parse(string)' always shows up?

Tags: c#

Suddenly I am getting the error below in every console application I make, including the ones I've already saved.

```
"The best overloaded method match for 'double.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments"
```

Can you tell me a possible reason for this other than 'j' is a Double and not a string since similar apps I made last week were working perfectly fine and now even they don't work because of the same error?

```
double i;
System.Console.WriteLine("Enter your weight.");
i = double.Parse(Console.ReadKey());
double j = (0.17 * i);
System.Console.WriteLine("Your weight on the moon will be" + j);
Console.ReadKey();`
```

Answer (score 8):

[`Console.ReadKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a  [`ConsoleKeyInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); you need `Console.ReadLine`.

You might also want to use `double.TryParse` to avoid possible exceptions for invalid values:

```
if(double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out i))
{
     double j = (0.17 * i);
     System.Console.WriteLine("Your weight on the moon will be" + j);
}
else 
{
    Console.WriteLine("You entered an invalid value!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`double.Parse(Console.ReadKey());` returns a `ConsoleKeyInfo` instance. You want `Console.ReadLine()` which returns a `string` instance. The error is generally saying the arguments don't match any of the methods definitions, you'll see it for all type of methods if you call them with the wrong arguments.